# Get all values by row index on all variables with names stored in a character data type

Tags: r

I have the following `xts` objects:

```r
A1 <- xts(x=c(1,2), order.by=c(as.Date("2019-09-29"),as.Date("2019-09-30")))
A2 <- xts(x=c(3,4), order.by=c(as.Date("2019-09-29"),as.Date("2019-09-30")))
```

Both variables are stored in a character:

```r
var_names <- c("A1", "A2")
```

Is there a way to get the values of the `2019-09-30` row from all the variables calling them from the character string `var_names`. So instead of doing this:

```r
cbind.data.frame(A1["2019-09-30"], A2["2019-09-30"])
```

Is there a way to do it without a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget`

```
do.call(cbind, mget(var_names))["2019-09-30"]
#            A1 A2
#2019-09-30  2  4
```

---

Or using `get`

```
cbind(A1 = get(var_names[1])["2019-09-30"], A2=get(var_names[2])["2019-09-30"])
```

Comment: Excellent, the first option is what I was looking for, really simple.